Deprecation Warnings in Flutter After Upgrading
After upgrading Flutter, I encountered the following two warnings related to my index.html file:
Warning: In index.html:37: Local variable for "serviceWorkerVersion" is deprecated. Use "{{flutter_service_worker_version}}" template token instead.
Warning: In index.html:46: "FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint" is deprecated. Use "FlutterLoader.load" instead.

These warnings indicate that certain elements in my index.html file are using deprecated methods. Here is my current index.html file:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <!--
        If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
        href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.
    
        The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
        it to work correctly.
    
        For more details:
        * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
    
        This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
        the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
      -->
      <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
    
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <meta name="description" content="chapter 04">
    
      <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="flutter_layout">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
    
      <!-- Favicon -->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    
      <title>flutter_layout</title>
      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    
      <script>
        // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
        const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
      </script>
      <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
      <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
          // Download main.dart.js
          _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
            serviceWorker: {
              serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
            },
            onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
              engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
                appRunner.runApp();
              });
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>


How do I replace the serviceWorkerVersion variable correctly using the {{flutter_service_worker_version}} template token?
How do I update the FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint method to use the new FlutterLoader.load method?

I appreciate any guidance or examples on how to resolve these deprecation warnings. Thank you!

Did you try what the deprecation messages told you already?

In web/index.html
1. Replace the serviceWorkerVersion
From
const serviceWorkerVersion = null;

To
const serviceWorkerVersion = {{flutter_service_worker_version}};

2. To fix the FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint warning, replace body
From
<body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
</script>
</body>

To
<body>
<script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
</body>

Learn more
https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/bootstrapping

remove web floder in your project, and enable web again.

